How to fetch parent data and all it's children, then aggregate to array?

Postgres: v12
Link to test:
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pfnFVhFq1QTxjas6BB4sZv/3

There are transactions table and logs table. logs are linked to transactions by transaction_id. I need to query logs by address, join it with transactions, aggregate logs to array, LIMIT transactions (example is LIMIT 2) and FETCH ALL LOGS that were in that transaction (but query only by one address field). transactions.hash is varchar.
create table transactions
(hash varchar,
 block_number integer,
 t_value varchar
);
 
insert into transactions values 
('h1',120,'v1'),
('h2',170,'v2'),
('h3',130,'v3'),
('h4',160,'v4'),
('h5',142,'v5')
;

create table logs
(transaction_hash varchar,
 address varchar,
 l_value varchar,
 l_trans_block_number integer -- this value duplicates from transactions for any case
);
 
insert into logs values 
('h1', 'a1', 'h1.a1.1', 120),
('h1', 'a1', 'h1.a1.2', 120),
('h1', 'a3', 'h1.a3.1', 120),
('h2', 'a1', 'h2.a1.1', 170),
('h2', 'a2', 'h2.a2.1', 170),
('h2', 'a2', 'h2.a2.2', 170),
('h2', 'a3', 'h2.a3.1', 170),
('h3', 'a2', 'h3.a2.1', 130),
('h4', 'a1', 'h4.a1.1', 160),
('h5', 'a2', 'h5.a2.1', 142),
('h5', 'a3', 'h5.a3.1', 142)
;


create index on transaction(hash);
create index on transaction(block_number);
create index on logs(address);
create index on logs(l_trans_block_number);

Result must be with query WHERE log.address='a2' LIMIT 2:
hash    block_number    t_value logs_array
h2      170             v2      {"{"address" : "a1", "l_value" : "h2.a1.1", "l_trans_block_number" : 170}","{"address" : "a2", "l_value" : "h2.a2.1", "l_trans_block_number" : 170}","{"address" : "a2", "l_value" : "h2.a2.2", "l_trans_block_number" : 170}","{"address" : "a3", "l_value" : "h2.a3.1", "l_trans_block_number" : 170}"}
h5      142             v5      {"{"address" : "a2", "l_value" : "h5.a2.1", "l_trans_block_number" : 142}","{"address" : "a3", "l_value" : "h5.a3.1", "l_trans_block_number" : 142}"}

Problem: sql query below works correct, but on very high amount of logs (100k+ logs for 1 address) it can take many minutes for search. The solution would be set LIMIT in MATERIALIZED, but in that case I can get transactions with not fully correct list of logs. How to fix? Either rewrite query without MATERIALIZED and use multiple SELECT inside each other, but I don't know how, or fix with MATERIALIZED.
So problem is that Postgres does not understand correct in MATERIALIZED that I need limited number of transactions, it first searches all logs, only then append them to transactions with limit (as I guess). Index on logs(address) is set.
WITH 
    b AS MATERIALIZED (
        SELECT lg.transaction_hash
        FROM logs lg
        WHERE lg.address='a2'
      
        -- this must be commented, otherwise not correct results, although fast execution
        -- ORDER BY lg.l_trans_block_number DESC
        -- LIMIT 2
    )
SELECT 
    hash,
    block_number,
    t_value,
    (SELECT array_agg(JSON_BUILD_OBJECT('address',address,'l_value',l_value,'l_trans_block_number',l_trans_block_number)) FROM logs WHERE transaction_hash = t.hash) logs_array
FROM transactions t 
WHERE t.hash IN 
    (SELECT transaction_hash FROM b)
ORDER BY t.block_number DESC -- must be ordered by block_number
LIMIT 2

Real-world example, query was executing ~30 seconds (in db I have transaction_id integer, but it's not increasing primary key):
EXPLAIN WITH 
    b AS MATERIALIZED (
        SELECT lg.transaction_id
        FROM _logs lg
        WHERE lg.address in ('0xca530408c3e552b020a2300debc7bd18820fb42f', '0x68e78497a7b0db7718ccc833c164a18d8e626816')
    )
SELECT 
    (SELECT array_agg(JSON_BUILD_OBJECT('address',address)) FROM _logs WHERE transaction_id = t.id) logs_array
FROM _transactions t 
WHERE t.id IN 
    (SELECT transaction_id FROM b)
LIMIT 5000;
                                                                    QUERY PLAN
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=87540.62..3180266.26 rows=5000 width=32)
   CTE b
     ->  Index Scan using _logs_address_idx on _logs lg  (cost=0.70..85820.98 rows=76403 width=8)
           Index Cond: ((address)::text = ANY ('{0xca530408c3e552b020a2300debc7bd18820fb42f,0x68e78497a7b0db7718ccc833c164a18d8e626816}'::text[]))
   ->  Nested Loop  (cost=1719.64..47260423.09 rows=76403 width=32)
         ->  HashAggregate  (cost=1719.07..1721.07 rows=200 width=8)
               Group Key: b.transaction_id
               ->  CTE Scan on b  (cost=0.00..1528.06 rows=76403 width=8)
         ->  Index Only Scan using _transactions_pkey on _transactions t  (cost=0.57..2.79 rows=1 width=8)
               Index Cond: (id = b.transaction_id)
         SubPlan 2
           ->  Aggregate  (cost=618.53..618.54 rows=1 width=32)
                 ->  Index Scan using _logs_transaction_id_idx on _logs  (cost=0.57..584.99 rows=6707 width=43)
                       Index Cond: (transaction_id = t.id)
 JIT:
   Functions: 17
   Options: Inlining true, Optimization true, Expressions true, Deforming true
(17 rows)

Adding DISTINCT to query took ~10 seconds (but anyway also needs ORDER BY inside MATERIALIZED:
EXPLAIN WITH 
    b AS MATERIALIZED (
        SELECT DISTINCT lg.transaction_id
        FROM _logs lg
        WHERE lg.address in ('0xca530408c3e552b020a2300debc7bd18820fb42f', '0x68e78497a7b0db7718ccc833c164a18d8e626816')
        LIMIT  5000
    )
SELECT 
    (SELECT array_agg(JSON_BUILD_OBJECT('address',address)) FROM _logs WHERE transaction_id = t.id) logs_array
FROM _transactions t 
WHERE t.id IN 
    (SELECT transaction_id FROM b)
;
                                                                          QUERY PLAN
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Nested Loop  (cost=87079.76..3211065.34 rows=5000 width=32)
   CTE b
     ->  Limit  (cost=86916.69..86966.69 rows=5000 width=8)
           ->  HashAggregate  (cost=86916.69..87443.81 rows=52712 width=8)
                 Group Key: lg.transaction_id
                 ->  Index Scan using _logs_address_idx on _logs lg  (cost=0.70..86723.67 rows=77206 width=8)
                       Index Cond: ((address)::text = ANY ('{0xca530408c3e552b020a2300debc7bd18820fb42f,0x68e78497a7b0db7718ccc833c164a18d8e626816}'::text[]))
   ->  HashAggregate  (cost=112.50..114.50 rows=200 width=8)
         Group Key: b.transaction_id
         ->  CTE Scan on b  (cost=0.00..100.00 rows=5000 width=8)
   ->  Index Only Scan using _transactions_pkey on _transactions t  (cost=0.57..2.79 rows=1 width=8)
         Index Cond: (id = b.transaction_id)
   SubPlan 2
     ->  Aggregate  (cost=624.68..624.69 rows=1 width=32)
           ->  Index Scan using _logs_transaction_id_idx on _logs  (cost=0.57..590.78 rows=6778 width=43)
                 Index Cond: (transaction_id = t.id)
 JIT:
   Functions: 19
   Options: Inlining true, Optimization true, Expressions true, Deforming true
(19 rows)


Please explain why LIMIT returns incorrect results. Since you do not use ORDER BY, LIMIT will return arbitrary results.

@Parfait just compare return results. With LIMIT in MATERIALIZED and without. https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pfnFVhFq1QTxjas6BB4sZv/0

You should just add DISTINCT keyword to your CTE named b and use LIMIT 2 in the CTE. You don't need LIMIT in main sql anymore:
WITH 
    b AS MATERIALIZED
      ( Select  DISTINCT lg.transaction_hash
        From    logs lg
        Where   lg.address='a2'
        LIMIT 2
      )
Select    hash, t_value,
          ( Select   ARRAY_AGG( JSON_BUILD_OBJECT('address', address, 'l_value', l_value) ) 
            From     logs 
            Where    transaction_hash = t.hash
          ) logs_array
From     transactions t 
Where    t.hash IN( Select transaction_hash From b)

Without DISTINCT keyword CTE b results with two rows - both with  'h2' value....
See the fiddle here.
Instead of DISTINCT keyword you could use Group By to get the same result...
WITH 
    b AS MATERIALIZED
      ( Select  lg.transaction_hash
        From    logs lg
        Where   lg.address='a2'
        Group By lg.transaction_hash
        LIMIT 2
      )
... ....

See it here.
UPDATED ANSWER (after question update):
WITH 
    b AS MATERIALIZED
      ( Select  lg.l_trans_block_number, lg.transaction_hash
        From    logs lg
        Where   lg.address='a2'
        Group By lg.l_trans_block_number, lg.transaction_hash
        Order By lg.l_trans_block_number Desc, lg.transaction_hash
        LIMIT 2
      )
Select    hash, block_number, t_value,
          ( Select   ARRAY_AGG( JSON_BUILD_OBJECT('address', address, 'l_value', l_value, 'l_trans_block_number', l_trans_block_number) ) 
            From     logs 
            Where    transaction_hash = t.hash And l_trans_block_number = t.block_number
          ) logs_array
From     transactions t 
Where    t.hash IN( Select transaction_hash From b)

R e s u l t :



hash
block_number
t_value
logs_array




h2
170
v2
{"{"address" : "a1", "l_value" : "h2.a1.1", "l_trans_block_number" : 170}","{"address" : "a2", "l_value" : "h2.a2.1", "l_trans_block_number" : 170}","{"address" : "a2", "l_value" : "h2.a2.2", "l_trans_block_number" : 170}","{"address" : "a3", "l_value" : "h2.a3.1", "l_trans_block_number" : 170}"}


h5
142
v5
{"{"address" : "a2", "l_value" : "h5.a2.1", "l_trans_block_number" : 142}","{"address" : "a3", "l_value" : "h5.a3.1", "l_trans_block_number" : 142}"}



See it here.

Thank you for reply. Works correct, but with DISTINCT not I have an error: for SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list, because in real app I use ORDER BY lg.l_value inside MATERIALIZED. I added this SELECT DISTINCT lg.transaction_hash, lg.l_value, error is gone, but wrong results. How to fix?

@sirjay One option could be to do the order by in From clause using subquery. "From    (Select * From logs Order By l_value) lg",  see it at the fiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/Il4gIROQ

@sirjay If your data looks like in question then you can Order By lg.transaction_hash. Filtering the result to addres = 'a2' with l_value constructed as hash.addres.order_number gives you just hashes with 'a2' address and you need just 2 distinct hashes. Are you sure you need that Order By l_value???

(Select * From logs Order By l_value) will cost a lot of time, won't it? I added DISTINCT to EXPLAIN even without ORDER BY and it took ~10 seconds to execute. Check my question, I added this.

@sirjay Again, with the data as in  the sample that Order By doesn't make sense, but if the data are different and you need it then this will cost some time, that's true. On the other hand this will give you a big benefit of aggregating  just the two predefined logs_array out of many. I would try something else if I would know what's that Order By l_value all about.

@sirjay Here is another option - using Group By instead of Distinct and taking just the Min(l_value) of a transaction_hash with address = 'a2'. https://dbfiddle.uk/qnj1NttF This makes Order By irrelevant cause there will be one hash and it's minimal value of l_value column. Sorry, but I just don't get it. The only Order By here that makes sense to me is Order By transaction_hash.

hm.. I need ORDER BY l_value 100% (meaning to get latest data, ordered by l_value). We can rename l_value to l_blocknumber. So the problem is to get by latest l_blocknumber limited by 2.

@sirjay But you are selecting hash  and t_value from transactions - logs table data are array aggregated for two transaction hashes that are filtered by address = 'a2'. So, you have rows of transaction hashes having address 'a2'. There could be many 'a2' rows per every  transaction hash in logs table but all of them have the same transaction hash. The log's l_value columns conttaining 'h2.a2.1' and 'h2.a2.2' ( or 'h2.a2.999' ) all have the same h2 transaction hash that is used as array_agg filter --> "Where    t.hash IN( Select transaction_hash From b)"

So you mean it will be Group By lg.transaction_hash, lg.l_value ORDER BY lg.l_value, lg.transaction_hash to get results as in base example?

@sirjay Without l_value completely. It is either Distinct or Group By. See the answer. Aggregated array, if hash has address a2,will have all the values anyway. If you group by both hash and l_value there will be two rows - both with hash h2 ... You don't need l_value in Msterialized cte at all.

With l_value ordered don't you know how to do? :) that's extremely important (because of getting latest sorted data by l_value)

@sirjay Quote "(because of getting latest sorted data by l_value)" end quote. Which data and getting them where? Again, you are selecting hash and t_value from transaction table, and an array  of data from logs table for two hashes containing address a2. Determining two hashes shoud be two "latest" ordered by l_value,  What is latest l_value (string) in this csse. Why don't yoiu provide sample data and ecpected result with logic described. Sample data that would reflect the usefullness of order by .. This data doesn't... I can't answer without the data reflecting the issue.

Sorry for misunderstanding, I corrected a question and fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pfnFVhFq1QTxjas6BB4sZv/3

@sirjay Just posted an update. Now it should be ok...
